# Salesforce CTI integration with Avaya

Tags: service-cloud-console, cti, opencti

I'm very new to salesforce. I have a client requirement to integrate the Salesforce Open CTI with avaya.

I don't know what steps to be followed to do it.

Is there any coding involved in it ?

I need some reference materials - to work on it.

I found this document in the online (This document describes installation and Configuration to setup Avaya with Open CTI): https://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/101027832

Is the procedure in this document is enough to setup ?

Kindly, someone please help me with this.